# @ngrx selector emitting twice in parallel

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I have a quite simple selector

```
export const isLoading = createSelector(
  state => state.$loading
);
```

and two actions `StartLayoutNavigationAction` and `EndLayoutNavigationAction` that just set the `$loading` flag accordingly.
I invoke these functions once, my actions get logged:

```
ACTION – [Layout] Start navigation StartLayoutNavigationAction {layout: "login", type: "[Layout] Start navigation"}
ACTION – [Layout] End navigation EndLayoutNavigationAction {type: "[Layout] End navigation"}
```

So one would assume that the selector would emit once when the first action was invoked, and once when the second one was invoked. No actions in between.

BUT:

The selector seems to emit twice in parallel. I piped as following:

```
layoutLoading$: Observable<boolean> = this.store.pipe(
  select(isLoading),
  distinctUntilChanged((x, y) => {
    console.log("Comparison:", x, y);
    return x === y;
  }),
  tap(value => console.log("New val:", value))
);
```

And this is the output:

```
ACTION – [Layout] Start navigation StartLayoutNavigationAction {layout: "login", type: "[Layout] Start navigation"}
Comparison:  false true
New val: true
Comparison: false true
New val: true
ACTION – [Layout] End navigation EndLayoutNavigationAction {type: "[Layout] End navigation"}
Comparison: true false
New val: false
Comparison: true false
New val: false
```

Am I getting something wrong? Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure that `layoutLoading$` have exactly one `subscription`? For example you have multiple `async` pipe, multiple component instance

Comment: Ok you're right, I have two subscriptions with `async`. I didn't know that this works per subscription. So when I want to react to distinct changes (in addition to the `async` pipes), I will need a second observable pipe, right?

Comment: added answer to close the question (if it correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Based on comments**

> Are you sure that layoutLoading$ have exactly one subscription? For
>   example you have multiple async pipe, multiple component instance. - @Buggy

```
const source$ = of(1).pipe(
  tap(value => console.log("New val:", value))
);

source$.subscribe();
source$.subscribe();
// 1
// 1
```

> Ok you're right, I have two subscriptions with async. I didn't know
>   that this works per subscription. So when I want to react to distinct
>   changes (in addition to the async pipes), I will need a second
>   observable pipe, right? - @Giacomo Voß

Yes, if i understood correctly:

```
source$
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged(fn))
  .subscribe(/* do something */)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time the state changes your selector will execute. This is because it's parameter is the whole state.

Comment: As you can see in my log, there is only one action executed, so one change to the state. But the selector registers the same change twice and executes twice with the same parameter.

Comment: Ah I see, do you have a reproduction?

Comment: I've tried your suggesstion too, but it didn't work for me. Please see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57094478/ngrx-selector-emits-when-anything-on-the-state-changes-memoization-of-selector-n) which has a reproduction with it.

Comment: it seems like on initial load, the selectors are called twice?